# Rewriting integrals over spheres involving $1/|x|$

Tags: analysis, vector-analysis, harmonic-functions

The following derivation cames from calculations related to the Laplace equation and its fundamental solution. Let $g(x)$ be a test-function (meaning compact support and infinitely differentiable), and we are on the space $\mathbb R^n$, then
$$
 \int_{\partial B(0,\delta)} \frac{1}{n\alpha(n)|x|^{n-1}} g(x) dS(x)
   = \frac{1}{n\alpha(n)\delta^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B(0,\delta)} g(x) dS(x)
$$
where $\alpha(n)$ denotes [volume of the unit all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball) in $\mathbb R^n$. The derivation comes form [this document](http://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/laplace.pdf), page 5, second step.

Why does this hold? For example let $n=2$, if I compute for $\delta > 0$
$$
 \int_{\partial B(0,\delta)} \frac{1}{|x|} dx
  = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\delta} \frac{1}{r} r dr d\theta
  = 2\pi \int_0^{\delta} 1 dr = 2\pi \delta
$$
which is not equal to $1/\delta$?

Comment: You do not perform a proper integration over the surface of the 2d-ball, here the rim of a disc. It would go just over the angular component, not the radial (which is constant, as martini stated).

Comment: you should not use the tags "functional analysis" and "distribution theory" for trivial vector analysis questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you integrate over $B(0,\delta)$, the *ball* of radius $\delta$. Note that on the *sphere* $\partial B(0,\delta) = \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid |x| = \delta\}$ we have $|x| = \delta$ by the very definition of the set. That is $\frac 1{|x|}$ is constant on the sphere, as is every power of it.

---

For $n = 2$, $B(0,\delta) = \delta S^1$, which has length $2\pi \delta$, giving 
$$ \int_{\delta S^1} \frac 1{|x|} \, dx = \int_{\delta S^1} \frac 1\delta \, dx = 2\pi\delta \cdot \frac 1{\delta}  = 2\pi $$
Note that for $g=1$, $\int_{\partial B(0,\delta)}\,g(x)\, dS(x) = n\alpha(n)\delta^{n-1}$ cancels the denominator.